# WPF TabControl - Preventing Unload on Tab Change?

Tags: wpf, caching, tabcontrol

Is there a way to prevent the Tab Unload/Reload when a tab changes in a WPF tab control? Or if that is not possible, is there a recommended method for caching the tabs contents so they don't have to be regenerated with each tab change?

For example, one tab's UI is completely customizable and stored in the database. When the user selects an object to work on, the items in the customized layout get populated with that object's data. Users expect a minor delay on initial load or when retrieving data, but not when changing back and forth between tabs, and the delay when changing tabs is very noticeable.

Comment: I don't think TabItems are unloaded/reloaded whenever the selected item in the tab control changes.  I'm not sure but maybe the SelectionChanged logic of your TabControl needs to be changed so that it doesn't re-query the database every time?

Comment: The Loaded/Unloaded events of the DataTemplates get run every time I change tabs (I'm using the MVVM design pattern)

Comment: So, in your application, whenever the selected tab changes, it triggers a connection to the database to retrieve the object's data?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to either cache the tab so it doesn't have to rebuild it or do some kind of workaround to prevent it from unloading/reloading the contents anytime the tab changes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a workaround here (web-archive-link, since site is down): https://web.archive.org/web/20120429044747/http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28

It basically stores the ContentPresenter of the tab and loads that up when switching tabs instead of redrawing it. It was still causing the delay when dragging/dropping tabs since that was an remove/add operation, however with some modifications I got that to go away as well (ran the Remove code at a lower dispatcher priority then the Add code, so the add operation had a chance to cancel the Remove operation and use the old ContentPresenter instead of drawing a new one)

**Edit:** The link above appears to no longer work, so I'll paste a copy of the code here. It's been modified a bit to allow dragging/dropping, but it should still work the same way.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

// Extended TabControl which saves the displayed item so you don't get the performance hit of 
// unloading and reloading the VisualTree when switching tabs

// Obtained from http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28
// and made a some modifications so it reuses a TabItem's ContentPresenter when doing drag/drop operations

[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class TabControlEx : System.Windows.Controls.TabControl
{
    // Holds all items, but only marks the current tab's item as visible
    private Panel _itemsHolder = null;

    // Temporaily holds deleted item in case this was a drag/drop operation
    private object _deletedObject = null;

    public TabControlEx()
        : base()
    {
        // this is necessary so that we get the initial databound selected item
        this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// if containers are done, generate the selected item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get the ItemsHolder and generate any children
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _itemsHolder = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// when the items change we remove any generated panel children and add any new ones as necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _itemsHolder.Children.Clear();

                if (base.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    base.SelectedItem = base.Items[0];
                    UpdateSelectedItem();
                }

                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:

                // Search for recently deleted items caused by a Drag/Drop operation
                if (e.NewItems != null && _deletedObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        if (_deletedObject == item)
                        {
                            // If the new item is the same as the recently deleted one (i.e. a drag/drop event)
                            // then cancel the deletion and reuse the ContentPresenter so it doesn't have to be 
                            // redrawn. We do need to link the presenter to the new item though (using the Tag)
                            ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                            if (cp != null)
                            {
                                int index = _itemsHolder.Children.IndexOf(cp);

                                (_itemsHolder.Children[index] as ContentPresenter).Tag =
                                    (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
                            }
                            _deletedObject = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    {

                        _deletedObject = item;

                        // We want to run this at a slightly later priority in case this
                        // is a drag/drop operation so that we can reuse the template
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
                            new Action(delegate()
                        {
                            if (_deletedObject != null)
                            {
                                ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                                if (cp != null)
                                {
                                    this._itemsHolder.Children.Remove(cp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ));
                    }
                }

                UpdateSelectedItem();
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Replace not implemented yet");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// update the visible child in the ItemsHolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generate a ContentPresenter for the selected item
    /// </summary>
    void UpdateSelectedItem()
    {
        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // generate a ContentPresenter if necessary
        TabItem item = GetSelectedTabItem();
        if (item != null)
        {
            CreateChildContentPresenter(item);
        }

        // show the right child
        foreach (ContentPresenter child in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            child.Visibility = ((child.Tag as TabItem).IsSelected) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// create the child ContentPresenter for the given item (could be data or a TabItem)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter CreateChildContentPresenter(object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);

        if (cp != null)
        {
            return cp;
        }

        // the actual child to be added.  cp.Tag is a reference to the TabItem
        cp = new ContentPresenter();
        cp.Content = (item is TabItem) ? (item as TabItem).Content : item;
        cp.ContentTemplate = this.SelectedContentTemplate;
        cp.ContentTemplateSelector = this.SelectedContentTemplateSelector;
        cp.ContentStringFormat = this.SelectedContentStringFormat;
        cp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        cp.Tag = (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
        _itemsHolder.Children.Add(cp);
        return cp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the CP for the given object.  data could be a TabItem or a piece of data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter FindChildContentPresenter(object data)
    {
        if (data is TabItem)
        {
            data = (data as TabItem).Content;
        }

        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (ContentPresenter cp in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            if (cp.Content == data)
            {
                return cp;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// copied from TabControl; wish it were protected in that class instead of private
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected TabItem GetSelectedTabItem()
    {
        object selectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_deletedObject == selectedItem)
        { 

        }

        TabItem item = selectedItem as TabItem;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(base.SelectedIndex) as TabItem;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think StackOverflow is just parsing the link's markdown incorrectly. It works if you copy/paste the entire URL (or don't use the \[\] markdown).
http://web.archive.org/web/20110825185059/http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28

Comment: I'm trying to make use of your solution, as it seems to solve the exact problem I face. However, I don't know exactly how to finish the job...  The variable `_itemsHolder` is always `null`, for example.  The control is in my XAML and everything displays correctly, but is there a particular reference in XAML that I need to bridge the gap?

Comment: @DonBoitnott At what point is it null? You said it works correctly, so it must get populated at some point.

Comment: Well, "correctly" only in the sense that everything displays properly.  It's instantiated in `OnApplyTemplate` by a call to `GetTemplateChild`, and it's null at that point and beyond.  Worth mentioning that I'm new to WPF and I have no idea what "PART_ItemsHolder" is for.

Comment: @DonBoitnott If it's set in `OnApplyTemplate`, then it should be there. Are you sure you're looking at the same instance of the object model? At what point are you placing a breakpoint and seeing it is null? It might be best to raise a new question if you're having an issue with this, so we can see relevant code. Also, I believe "PART_ItemsHolder" is a section of the default WPF TabControl template

Comment: @Rachel The answer to my problem ended up being the `ControlTemplate` defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802346/1633308).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this, I had a similar problem and managed to solve it by caching a user control that represented the contents of a tab item in the code behind.

In my project I have a tab control that is bound to a collection (MVVM).  However the first tab is an overview that shows a summary of all of the other tabs in a list view.  The problem I was having was that whenever a user moves their selection from an item tab to the overview tab, the overview is redrawn with all of the summary data, which can take 10-15 seconds depending on the number of items in the collection. (note their is no reloading of actual data from a db or anything, it is purely the drawing of the summary view that was taking the time).

What I wanted was for this loading of the summary view to only occur once when the data context is first loaded and any subsequent switching between tabs to be instantaneous.

Solution:

Classes involved: 
MainWindow.xaml - The main page containing the tab control. 
MainWindow.xaml.cs - Code behind for above. 
MainWindowViewModel.cs - View model for the above view, contains the collection. 
Overview.xaml - User control that draws the overview tab item content. 
OverviewViewModel.cs - View model for the above view.

Steps:

1. Replace the datatemplate in 'MainWindow.xaml' that draws the overview tab item with a blank user control named 'OverviewPlaceholder'
2. Make the reference to 'OverviewViewModel' public within 'MainWindowViewModel.cs'
3. Add a static reference to 'Overview' in 'MainWindow.xaml.cs'
4. Add an event handler to the loaded event of user control 'OverviewPlaceholder', within this method instantiate the static reference to 'Overview' only if it is null, set the datacontext of this reference to the 'OverviewViewModel' reference within the current datacontext (that is 'MainWindowViewModel') and set the place holder's content to be the static reference to 'Overview'.

Now the overview page is only drawn once because each time it is loaded (i.e. the user clicks onto the overview tab), it puts the already rendered, static user control back onto the page.

Answer (score -3):

I have a really simple solution to avoid the tab reload on tab change,
use a contentPresenter in the tabItem instead of the content property.

e.g.(in MVVM style)

replace

> ```
>       <TabItem Header="Tab1" Content="{Binding Tab1ViewModel}" />
> ```

by

> ```
>         <TabItem Header="Tab1">
>             <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Tab1ViewModel}" />
>         </TabItem>
> ```

Comment: Why this answer is upvoted? `ContentPresenter` will be unloaded on tab switching including its content. This does nothing.

Comment: As the other user said, this does nothing.