# Keep WPF Popup child loaded

Tags: wpf, user-controls, popup

I have a WPF Popup control that has a custom control as its child. Apparently, the child is loaded when the popup opens and unloaded when the popup closes. There is a considerable amount  of work to be done when the child is loaded, however, so I would like to keep it loaded.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: How about some code? What do you mean exactly by *I would like to keep it loaded*?

Comment: A `TabControl` has the same problem with loading/unloading it's `TabItems`. As a workaround, I use a [customized `TabControl`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3627308/302677) that stores the `ContentPresenter` on unload, and re-uses it on load instead of redrawing it. Perhaps you could use some of its code to create a customized Popup with the same behavior?

Comment: Rachel, I just noticed that you linked to your example. Thanks.