# 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a tab control in the GUI and there is WPF 4.0 datagrid in one of the tabs. When I click on a cell in the grid and edit something and then switch tabs, I get a Defer Refresh error:

> DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.

So I call `datagrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row)` when tab is switched to cancel any pending edit and the Defer refresh issue is gone.

But what I really want to do is `CommitEdit()` so that the user doesn't have to reenter the data again.

And `datagrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true)` doesn't work for me. 
I get the below error on `CommitEnd()`:

> Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is
>   suspended.

PS: I have tried datagrid.CommitEdit() and datagrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Column, true) and it didnt work.

Comment: Can you show code for the datagrid and the event.

Comment: Same bug seen when working over remote desktop and connection closes during edit (possibly happens just from PC going to sleep and RDP is a red herring). Fixed by doing the same CommitEdit() call in response to SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged. Make sure to use WeakEventManager with this static event so you don't leak the grid, and/or unregister in Unloaded.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this by adding this handler for the DataGrid's Unloaded event:

```
    void DataGrid_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
        grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work. I was doing grid.CommitEdit() and wasn't working. I wonder why the parameters are necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've run in to this before.  WPF only keeps the current tab's view in memory; when you switch tabs, WPF unloads the current view and loads the view of the selected tab.  However, DataGrid throws this exception if is currently executing a AddNew or EditItem transaction and WPF tries to unload it.

The solution for me was to keep all the tab views in memory, but only set the current tab's view to visible.  This link shows a method of doing this:

[WPF TabControl - Preventing Unload on Tab Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601125/wpf-tabcontrol-preventing-unload-on-tab-change)

This change will also make your tabs load more smoothly when you switch between them because the view doesn't have to be regenerated.  In my case, the extra memory usage was a reasonable trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

In Xaml :

```
Loaded="OnUserControlLoaded"

Unloaded="OnUserControlUnloaded"
```

In Code Behind Inside `OnUserControlLoaded` and `OnUserControlUnloaded` Methods:

```
dataGrid.CommitEdit()

dataGrid.CancelEdit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem by "commiting" changes to the DataTable that is my source of datas.

So if you have a DataTable in the source you can try the following code :

```
DataTableSource.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that issue by adding this piece of code:

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {                               
             WPFdataGrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);                                
        }
    }
```

I think it's a problem of UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

`Commit()` on the `DataGrid` was not working for me, I've tried to call it on the collection view and it worked:

```
void DataGrid_OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable source = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource;
    var view = (IEditableCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source);
    view.CommitEdit();
}
```