# DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Tags: wpf

I am doing sorting in WPF on button click and use drag and drop technique
when I drag a `dll` file in WPF and then click again on button for sorting.

It gives an error of `DeferRefresh` is not allowed during an `AddNew` or EditItem transaction.

//My sorting code

```
if (_sortColumn == column)
        {

            _sortColumn = column;

            downImage = @"..\Images\icon-arrow-up-b-128.png";

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FilesView);

                _filesCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(_sortColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayedImageDown);
                _filesCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                _sortColumn = "";
    }
}
```

//My Drag code

```
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>(files);
        List<string> filepaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
            Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            long byteSize = fi.Length;
            //string stringSize = BytesToString(byteSize);
            string name = fi.Name;

            ListView listView = sender as ListView;

           ((ListCollectionView)FilesView.ItemsSource).AddNewItem((new FileViewModel(@"" + fi.DirectoryName + "/" + name)));//, itemSize = stringSize


}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281615/deferrefresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use DeferRefresh() to change the sort/group description. I heard that there's some change being made in .NET 4.5 but I never test it yet.

To solve this, Instead of using the DeferRefresh feature in CollectionView, you can implement all the control at your CustomObservableCollection that suspends change events on the collection in order to perform a bulk change operation by Begin/End Update call (seems like something similar comes with VS2015 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd867973.aspx) or just google "bulk batch update observable collection" for your own custom implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged.

By the way, if you have money to spend, a lot of 3rd party wpf controls package e.g. DevExpress, came with the Begin/EndDateUpdate on their controls. Will save a lot of your time implementing your own solution.

One note for using Begin/End update is that not all bulk update operations have performance gain. The idea is mainly "do whatever you want and then the control will do a whole data collection refresh". It works for sorting or grouping as everything needs to be re-render anyway. But, it might not be true for operations that updating a few cells or rows in one going. You need to test the performance on your own to find out which case is better.