# WPF - Inside DispatcherUnhandledException handler, how to locate the problematic code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which has many datagrids in different pages. I have seen InvalidOperationException being raised sometimes. Neither I could locate the code location where the issue happened, nor could I reproduce the issue.

[Edit] The stack trace has no information about the source of the problem in my code - i.e. I want to know where is the origin of the exception in my source code?

For example, the following stack trace was logged inside DispatcherUnhandledException when the problem occurred:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.
>          at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.DeferRefresh()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(CollectionView view)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
>          at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>          at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>          at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>          at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.ScheduleTransferOperation(Object arg)
>          at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.ProcessCrossThreadRequests()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

But from the above stack trace, I cannot figure out which code snippet in my project caused this. Is there any way to figure out the thread/method which caused this exception?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281615/deferrefresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction) should give you an idea of the cause.  The solution is apparently to cancel or commit an edit-in-progress when a data grid is unloaded.  You can try to reproduce by beginning to edit or add a row, then forcing the grid to unload by switching tabs or otherwise removing the grid from its visual free.

Comment: @Mike - Thanks for the link. May be, I didn't clearly state my question here: I used _"System.InvalidOperationException: DeferRefresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction"_ as an example. My question is, when we have DispatcherUnhandledException, can we get more info about the source thread/method from DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs?

Comment: It may not have been anything in your code.  This error seems to have occurred in response to a data grid's `ItemsSource` being changed while an edit was in progress, possibly because its binding was 'disconnected' when the grid was unloaded, or perhaps the data context changed.  Regardless, the exception occurred while the dispatcher was processing its queue, and I don't know any way to determine the call stack at the time the action was inserted into the queue.  You could configure VS to break on the inner exception type, and then try to inspect each call frame for clues.

Comment: Adding this link in case it may be helpful to someone looking at this section: [social.msdn_DispatcherUnhandledException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cb17dcd-15f7-4210-ab0d-730d03e07dc0/how-to-get-the-source-thread-or-method-info-from-dispatcherunhandledexception?forum=wpf&prof=required)