# WPF + TabControl Scope

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

In my WPF project I have a TabControl with several tab items.
Each Tab Item has a WPF control (view) and each view has a correspondent ViewModel.
Each time I click to change tab item I noticed that the control/view is unload and loaded again when I click the tab item again, the correspondent ViewModel stays in memory.

I m trying t build a simple RemoteDesktop/RDP client that uses 1 tab item per computer connection, so the problem is when I change tab item, the connection goes away because the view is unloaded...

I researched for some examples out there, but most of them are built in top of Winforms that has a different implementation from WPF.

So I was thinking if it is possible to prevent the View from going out of scope when I change from TabItem?

Does Any one knows about some sample online that uses WPF for tabbed RDP connections?
Thank you.

**UPDATE** - DataTemplate being used

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
        <v:DashboardView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Anyone? -Suggestions?

Comment: Where are the WPF masters?? :)

Comment: How do you implement the relationship between the views and the viewmodels? I mean... TabControlView <-> TabControlViewModel, TabItemView <-> TabItemViewModel, etc. How do you instantiate them?

Comment: Hi, I m using a different DataTemplate for each TabItem. I updated the initial post for you to see it.

Comment: Ok. Do you do something in the `Load` event or in the `GotFocus` event of the tabs?

Comment: No I do not....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here

[WPF TabControl - Preventing Unload on Tab Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601125/wpf-tabcontrol-preventing-unload-on-tab-change)

```
replace

      <TabItem Header="Tab1" Content="{Binding Tab1ViewModel}" />
by

        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Tab1ViewModel}" />
        </TabItem>
```